# GSpread open_by_url or open_by_key take a very very long time python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

i'm trying to make a python script to edit a spreadsheet, but just "connecting" to the sheet take around 2 minutes

I tried first with googles libs and code, and the default quickstart.py also took 3 minute to do anything

For google's it was HttpRequest function `execute()` that lasted for 2 minutes, for Gspread it's `open_by_url/key` both take 3 minutes.

Both code worked but i don't want to wait 3 minutes each time i want to change something.

```py
import gspread, time

lel = time.time()
gc = gspread.service_account()
sheet = gc.open_by_url('URL')

worksheet = sheet.worksheet("Quick Links")
worksheet_list = sheet.worksheets()

print(worksheet.get('A1').first())
print(time.time() - lel)
```

output :

```py
QUICK LINKS
169.46962642669678
```

I thought that reading a cell from a spreadsheet would take around 3-4 seconds, especially if you're not loading any of the "graphical" parts.

Comment: Hi if you notice the same issue on both libraries then it's not the code but your computer or network. Run the exact same script from a different computer then from a different computer from a different internet connection and check back to identify which is faculty I would recommend

Comment: It's actually fixed itself now, my theory is that the google sheet API wasn't full awaken, so it was slow, now that it's awake there's no problem.